# passing data back using coordinator pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, coordinator-pattern

How to pass data from VC-B to VC-A using coordinator pattern... Im getting error delegate = nil

In MainCoordinator:

```
func filterView() { 
let filterVC = FilterViewController.instantiate()
filterVC.delegate = self //error : cannot assign value of Type MainCoordinator to type FilterDelegate?
filterVC.coordinator = self
self.navigationController.present(filterVC)
}
```

In FilterViewController:

```
protocol FilterDelegate: class {
func data()}
class FilterViewController: UIViewController,StoryBoarded {
var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
weak var delegate: FilterDelegate?

@IBButton func onClick() {
self.delegate.data()
dismiss()
}
```

In MainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController,FilterDelegate {
var coordinator = MainCoordinator?
func data() {
Print("Data")
}
```

Tell me any other way to pass data back with coordinator?

Comment: where you are getting delegate nil ? please post both controllers

Comment: I assume the reference to `code` is just a typo introduced when creating the question. I assume you’re actually referencing `vc` there...